# How to generate a hash using ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp.net mvc. I need to generate a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="delete-field">Delete</a>
```

Using asp.net mvc ActionLink helper. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need the helper method here ? Simply use the html as in your question ?

Comment: @Shyju I am trying to make everything consistant. It's ok if this cannot be done. I'll just let my code reviewer know this if its pointed out.

Comment: For what reason you need to extend `@Html.ActionLink`? I think you're misidentify `#` sign with "hash", it is sign to make anchor link. Certainly you don't need to use `ActionLink` for anchors (links referred to certain element part in the same page).

Comment: Not using `@Html.ActionLink()`. Your could always create your own `HtmlHelper` extension  method, but that would probably be overkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, this works:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "index", null, new { @class = "delete-field", href = "#" })
```

But like previously mentioned, there's not a lot of point to doing something like that. You could also build an extension method (again, overkill):

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HashLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text, string className = "")
    {
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.InnerHtml = text;
        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(className))
        {
            anchor.AddCssClass(className);
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
@Html.HashLink("Delete", "delete-field")
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I switch to the `@Url.Action` method and add the hash in after the link, like so:

```
<a class="delete-field" href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")#hashvalue">Delete</a>
```

The `UrlHelper` just generates the `href` part of the `a` tag, so you can add things in if you like. [API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_)

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, `ActionLink` is there to create a link to an `Action` in your MVC application. Since you're just trying to create a link which doesn't use hash, I suggest you to use the HTML code as you posted in your question. No need to use `ActionLink` or any other helper here.